# Seaborn global hue order

Tags: seaborn

I very often use the `hue` argument to distinguish between categories but it seems like seaborn isn't consistent in how it matches hues to categories (from what I've read it depends on the plotted data, in particular its order). I would like to avoid passing the `hue_order` argument everywhere because I know I will forget it at some point and not notice it (which will lead to misinterpretations because I will suppose hues are correct).

Is there a way to set the `hue_order` globally (fixed order for all plots)?

Even better, would it possible to set categorical indexes to all behave the same (eg., alphanumeric order)?

For now I use the following ugly strategy:

```py
SNS_SETTINGS = dict(hue_order=[...])

sns.displot(df, **SNS_SETTINGS, x="time", kind="ecdf", hue="algorithm")
```

Comment: Asking to make sure of understanding your situation, don't you also put the `hue` parameter in the dictionary too, since they come in pair? Because in that case, you will "never" forget `hue_order` since you won't have `hue` either.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Also, I will use this constant in almost all my plots (not only `displot`s). That's probably a good solution indeed :D

Comment: I’m not sure the concept of a “global hue order” makes sense, because it implies you are only ever using one hue variable. What you can do is set a “category” dtype on the data object, which will provide the ordering information any time that data is used.

Comment: It depends, if you only have strings you could accept to sort all hues in alphabetical order. Its not perfect either though, it would be even better to have a hue per category, set globaly. This way even when you don't display all categories, the hue stays consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very practical solution is to add the `hue` parameter in the `SNS_SETTINGS` dictionary. This coupling will ensure the needed consistency across your plots.

Another solution, that may or may not be adequate in your specific case, would be to define custom functions with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), defining the parameters once to have shorter function calls:

```py
from functools import partial

displot_by_algorithm = partial(sns.displot, hue="algorithm", hue_order=[...])
```

This way, you can later call

```py
displot_by_algorithm(df, x="time", kind="ecdf")
```

Of course, you will have to define such function for all the different plotting functions you want to use, so the trade-off might not be worth it.

Comment: Yes thanks, I really think the first solution is the best fit for me, but using partial might be worth it in other cases. I would still love to tell seaborn how to behave (this way avoiding any confusion/error in the future). In the mean time I will accept your answer.